# Is it possible to make "get values that is not duplicated ​at all" algorithm, not using sort? (Time complexity => O(n)

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, time-complexity, big-o

i want to know "get values that is not duplicated ​​at all" algorithm without sort is possible.

let me explain about "get values that is not duplicated ​​at all"

if list value is  [1,3,3,2]

i want to get 1, 2

I tried lots of algorithms.

but i can't find an algorithm that has stable time complexity is O(n).

i tried using dict, queue.

However, always time complexity is not stable O(n)

using dict

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5]
li_dict = dict()
for i in range(len(li)):
    try:
        a = li_dict[li[i]]
        li_dict[li[i]] = False
    except KeyError:
        li_dict[li[i]] = True
for k in li_dict.keys():
    if li_dict[k]:
        print(k, end="")
```

is this possible?

if this is possible, please explain how to make it possible.
(without sort)

Comment: What about using a set to contain the already known elements, if the element is known remove it from the final elements list, it its not known add it to the known elements and to the final elements lists. You should be able to get the final elements list in a single iteration.

Comment: What do you mean by "stable"?

Comment: And how did you establish `always time complexity is not stable O(n)`?

Comment: `[k for k, count in collections.Counter(li).items() if count == 1]` is O(N)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that has O(N) expected time, but not worst case time.

Comment: @MattTimmermans because hashing is worst-case linear?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are lots of different hash table implementations, but none that I know of (certainly not anything that would be built into python) that could provide worst case O(1) for all operations without constraining the keys.

Comment: [k for k, count in collections.Counter(li).items() if count == 1] i tried this, but count system is written using repeat

Comment: @koder_ko what? what do you mean "count system is written using repeat"?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a hardcoded solution for you. You can make use of the [Set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) type:

```
li = [1,3,3,2]
result = set()
seen = set()

for i in li:
    if i in seen:
        result.discard(i)
    else:
        result.add(i)
        seen.add(i)

print(result)
```

Because python Sets use a hash table technique under the hood lookups are very fast, just as in dictionaries. Sets are a bit better suited for your problem however, because they behave more like lists.
In my code example i iterate over the list only once and as Set memberships tests are near instant (O(1)) I believe this is O(n) complexity.

I use two sets to seperate the items I've seen already from the items I want to keep.

There are more pythonic solutions most likely. This is my first attempt at reasoning the complexity of a piece of code, but i believe my conclusions are valid. If not, someone else may correct me!

Comment: I don't think this code's time complexity is always O(n), because of discard, add time complexity. However I think this is the best way to solve this problem.